# Storing an array into another array

Tags: arrays, assembly, 68000

I'm trying to copy array `A` into array `N` and then print the array (to test that it has worked) but all it outputs is `-1`

Here is my code:

```
    ORG    $1000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

    clr.w d1

    movea.w #A,a0
    movea.w #N,a2
    move.w #6,d2
for move.w (a0)+,(a2)+
    DBRA d2,for
    move.w #6,d2
loop
    move.l  (a2,D2),D1  ; get number from array at index D2
    move.b  #3,D0       ; display number in D1.L
    trap    #15

    dbra d2,loop



SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

A dc.w 2,2,3,4,5,6
N dc.l 6


END    START        ; last line of source
```

Why is `-1` in the output only? If there is a better solution for this that would be very helpful

Comment: A few things look suspicious at a glance: `N dc.l 6` - I'm pretty sure this will only allocate storage for a single long word (With the value 6), not allocate storage for 6 longs (as I think you want). `move.l  (a2,D2),D1  ; get number from array at index D0` <-- either the code or the comment is wrong. And it looks like you're not using `dbra` correctly (see e.g. [here](http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/codeopt/codeopt00/notes/constructs))

Comment: @user786653 You're right it should be `(a2,D2),D1 ; get number from array at index D2`. I don't know how dbra is used incorrectly, I want to decrement d2 until it reaches 0, otherwise loop. How would I allocate storage for 6 longs? Thanks

Comment: The linked page shows examples of correct and incorrect `dbra` usage, find one that matches your needs. How you allocate storage depends on what assembler you're using, but it'll usually be something like `ds.l`.

Comment: From what I can see my problem can be fixed either by going to `endl` which will start the loop OR decrement my number of loops by 1 since it would loop 6+1 times instead of 6. I tried the decrement and it still doesn't work, and I would prefer not to use `endl`. I forgot that to allocate storage is to use `ds.l` thanks.

Comment: Looks like your data sizes are all over the place. You're loading addresses as 16-bit (ok, you've org'd the code low-down in memory, but...), then copying words, but then you try to print them by indexing in bytes but loading as long-words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, your new array is only 4 bytes in size, you should change

dc.l 6 to ds.w 6

and also you work on 7 elements, since DBRA counts down to -1.

Second, and thats why you get -1 everywhere, you use A2 as pointer to the new array, but you do not reset it to point at the first word in new array. Since you increased it by one word per element during the copy, after the for loop has completed, A2 points to the first word *after* the array.

Your simulator outputting more than one number with your display loop indicates that your simulator does not emulate an MC68000, a *real* MC68000 would take a trap at "MOVE.L (A2,D2),D1" as soon as the sum of A2+D2 is odd - the 68000 does not allow W/L sized accesses to odd addresses (MC68020 and higher do).

A cleaned MC68000 compatible code could look like this:

```
     lea A,a0
     lea N,a2
     moveq #5,d2
 for move.w (a0)+,(a2)+
     dbra d2,for

     lea N,a2
     moveq #5,d2
 loop
     move.w  (a2)+,D1   ; get number (16 bits only)
     ext.l d1           ; make the number 32 bits
     moveq  #3,D0       ; display number in D1.L
     trap    #15
     dbra d2,loop
```

It probably contains some instructions you haven't encountered yet.

Comment: Thanks, but what does LEA do?

Comment: LEA (Load Effective Address) is somewhat similar to a MOVE in that it evaluates the first argument and loads the result into the destination register. LEA is specifically address only (thus it always generates full 32 bits result), and higher MC680x0 can perform this in the address generation unit instead of the ALU (which is faster). From a source code view, lea explicitly expresses that an address is evaluated and its syntax makes it less error prone (a good assembler should select the best addressing mode automatically without you specifying it).

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have access to whatever assembler/simulator you're using, I can't actually test it, but here a few things (some of which are already noted in the comments):

- `dc.l` declares a single long, you want `ds.l` (or similar) to allocate storage for 6 longs
- `dbra` branches until the operand is equal to `-1`, so you'll probably want to turn

  ```
  movw #loop_times, d0
  loop
     ....
     dbra d0, loop
  ```

  into

  ```
  movw #loop_times-1, d0
  loop
     ....
     dbra d0, loop
  ```

(this works as long as `loop_times` is > 0, otherwise you'll have to check the condition before entering the loop)

- You display loop has a few problems: 1. On entry `a2` points past the end of the `N` array. 2. Even fixing that, the way you're indexing it will cause problems. On the first entry you're trying to fetch a 4-byte long from address `a2 + 6`,then a long from `a2 + 5`...

What you want is to fetch longs from address `a2 + 0`, `a2 + 4` .... One way of doing that:

```
    move.w  #6-1, d2    ; note the -1
    movea.l #N, a2
loop
    move.l  (a2)+,D1    ; get next number from array
    ; use d1 here
    dbra    d2,loop
```